# List of publications for funding applications

Tags: funding

What does a "List of publications" mean? I'm applying for a scholarship and it says I have to add that file, so I need to know what this file should contain and if it's necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume they mean the list of your published work as in journal articles, conference proceedings, book chapters etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be **very** careful when preparing grant and funding applications to prepare the list of publications according to the specifications provided. Failing to do so can lead to your proposal being rejected, often without going to reviewers first.

For instance, the National Science Foundation expects each researcher to provide no more than **10** publications in her CV for a given proposal: five publications that are "most relevant" to the proposed work, plus five others deemed "important in the researchers' career." The German Research Foundation, however, simply says no more than 10 publications per researcher, but doesn't break down the categories. Other funding agencies have similar but slightly different rules.